# How to store variable length arrays in a database

Tags: php, mysql

I'm looking for a way to save data based off a set of rows in another table, but I don't know how to set up the field. Think something similar to using the results of a mysql `group_concat` as the field. The data is based off the **unique combination** of rows, rather than one row or field.

What I need to be able to do is:

1. Store the array itself in the database
2. Store associated data about the array
3. Retreive the array
4. The ability to lookup data about the array using the data in the array

Some options I've thought about:

1. Saving as an ordered set concatenated into a string.
2. Saving the serialized array (serialized using php's serialize function).
3. Saving the set as a hashed string using a reversible hash.

None of these options seem correct so I came here hoping someone has a better answer.

Background:

Supposed I have the following tables:

```
users {id, other unimportant fields}
products {id, other unimportant fields}
shipments {id, user_id, product_id, date, other unimportant fields}
```

I want to create a new table called `assigned_products` where the assigned product is based off of the **unique combination** of products they've received in the past. So `assigned_products` should look like:

```
assigned_products {set_of_products_received (array), product_id (data about the array)}
```

I don't know of a good way to store `set_of_products_received` in a database.

Example use:

Suppose I have 100 users who got product A, 100 users who got product B, and 100 users who got products A and B. Suppose then I wanted to give product B to everyone who got product A, product A to everyone who got product B, and product C to everyone who got product A and B. The assigned products table should look like:

```
+--------------------------+------------+
| set_of_products_received | product_id |
+--------------------------+------------+
| A                        | B          |
| B                        | A          |
| A, B                     | C          |
+--------------------------+------------+
```

I'm just looking for a better way of storing `set_of_products_received`

Reading this over I realize it's a bit hard to understand, but I don't really know the appropriate terms to describe this issue (probably why I'm having trouble finding solutions). I'll be happy to clarify if anyone has any questions.

Comment: This is not clear. What do you want in assigned_products? How does that relate to users?

Comment: This is very unclear, that said there are almost no circumstances where any of those approaches you mention is a good idea, you end up with something that is very difficult to search/edit/manage efficiently; databases like normalised tables, rows & columns and that is almost always what you should use.

Comment: I'll edit to try to make to make this clearer.

Comment: if you post picture that , that's how your table are at the moment and show the end result which you want, it will become clear

Comment: A table of unique `assigned_batch_id` E.g. `assigned_products_batch {assigned_batch_id, created_date, etc}` and `assigned_products {assigned_batch_id, product_id}` where `assigned_batch_id` is the same for each unique `product_id` ?

Comment: @AlexK. I need it to be reversible (I need to be able to get set of products from the database). How would you store that in your `assigned_products_batch` table?

Comment: As others have mentioned, this question is confusing. I suggest you reword it in terms of the task you are trying to accomplish from a business perspective, without any technical jargon. Please provide some examples of actual data.

Comment: I added more info, and removed references to the primary key so it doesn't distract from the core of the question.